# Can't get correct response when html has emoji by using Scrapy ( parsing Baidu Tieba post's doule-deck(lzl) )

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, scrapy, emoji

I'm a beginner learning Scrapy.

When I parsed Baidu Tieba's post, I found that if a post's double-check(in Chinese, named 'Lou Zhong Lou'(楼中楼), abbr.->lzl, and I will use 'lzl' when I mention it below) has emoji, Scrapy will not return me a correct response.

Here is my core code:

```python
# coding=utf-8
# filename: tieba_post_spider.py
# path: D:\WORK\PythonProject\ScrapyLearn\ScrapyTest\tutorial\tutorial\spiders\tieba_post_spider.py

import scrapy
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class TiebaPostSpider(scrapy.spiders.Spider):
    name = "tiebaPost"
    allowed_domains = ["tieba.baidu.com"]
    start_urls = [
        # 1. Has lzl, don't have emoji
        # "https://tieba.baidu.com/p/comment?tid=3886007864&pid=71342182567&pn=3"
        # 2. Has lzl, has emoji
        "https://tieba.baidu.com/p/comment?tid=5301206923&pid=111389280437&pn=1"
        # 3. Don't have lzl
        # "https://tieba.baidu.com/p/comment?tid=5301206923&pid=111390028140&pn=1"
    ]
    # I tried to change header to fix it but I failed :(
    custom_settings = {
        'DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS': {
            'Accept': '*/*',
            'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
            'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                          'Chrome/48.0.2564.116 Safari/537.36',
        }
    }

    # Parse lzl, if there isn't lzl then print nothing, or print username and his/her words
    def parse(self, response):
        # Use BeautifulSoup's CSS selector to get tags
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.body, "lxml")
        # Collect this page's all users' words and print them
        lzl_content = soup.select("li[class^='lzl_single_post j_lzl_s_p']")
        if len(lzl_content) != 0:
            for single_post in lzl_content:
                content = single_post.select("div.lzl_cnt")[0]
                username = content.select("a")[0].attrs['username']
                words = content.select("span")[0].get_text()
                print username + u": " + words
        # If lzl has next page, request next page and parse it
        lzl_next = soup.select("li.lzl_li_pager.j_lzl_l_p.lzl_li_pager_s p a")
        if len(lzl_next) != 0:
            for h in lzl_next:
                href = h.attrs['href']
                text = h.get_text().encode('GB18030')
                if text == u'下一页'.encode('GB18030'):
                    index = response.url.find("&pn=")
                    next_url = response.url[:index+4] + href[1:]
                    yield scrapy.Request(next_url, callback=self.parse)
```

As you can see, there are 3 urls to be parsed, and here is result:

1. Has lzl, don't have emoji, it can be parsed successfully, all users' words can be shown in cmd.
2. Has lzl, has emoji, it **cannot** be parsed because error occurred ( and incorrect response above by using *print soup* in *parse* function ):

[image]

3. Don't have lzl, in this case, there isn't anything will be printed, and spider ends with no error occurred.

PS: If emoji **appears in post** instead of lzl, it will **be parsed as *"??"*** in response.

So, why **incorrect response returned** while Scrapy meet emoji in lzl?

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you shouldn't mix Scrapy and BS4. It is not needed. You will find yourself in messes like one you are in right now. Below is a corrected version of your code in just scrapy. This works fine

```
import scrapy

class TiebaPostSpider(scrapy.spiders.Spider):
    name = "tiebaPost"
    allowed_domains = ["tieba.baidu.com"]
    start_urls = [
        # 1. Has lzl, don't have emoji
         "https://tieba.baidu.com/p/comment?tid=3886007864&pid=71342182567&pn=3",
        # 2. Has lzl, has emoji
        "https://tieba.baidu.com/p/comment?tid=5301206923&pid=111389280437&pn=1",
        # 3. Don't have lzl
         "https://tieba.baidu.com/p/comment?tid=5301206923&pid=111390028140&pn=1",
    ]
    # I tried to change header to fix it but I failed :(
    custom_settings = {
        'DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS': {
            'Accept': '*/*',
            'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
            'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                          'Chrome/48.0.2564.116 Safari/537.36',
        }
    }

    # Parse lzl, if there isn't lzl then print nothing, or print username and his/her words
        def parse(self, response):
    emoji_pattern = re.compile(
        u"(\ud83d[\ude00-\ude4f])|"  # emoticons
        u"(\ud83c[\udf00-\uffff])|"  # symbols & pictographs (1 of 2)
        u"(\ud83d[\u0000-\uddff])|"  # symbols & pictographs (2 of 2)
        u"(\ud83d[\ude80-\udeff])|"  # transport & map symbols
        u"(\ud83c[\udde0-\uddff])"  # flags (iOS)
        "+", flags=re.UNICODE)
    # Collect this page's all users' words and print them
    lzl_content = response.css("li[class^='lzl_single_post j_lzl_s_p']")
    if len(lzl_content) != 0:
        for single_post in lzl_content:
            content = single_post.css("div.lzl_cnt")
            username = content.css("a::attr(username)").extract_first().strip()
            words_list = content.css("span::text").extract()
            words = ""
            for word in words_list:
                words += word
            if emoji_pattern.search(words):
                words = words.encode('unicode-escape')
            print username + ":" + words

    # If lzl has next page, request next page and parse it
    lzl_next = response.css("li.lzl_li_pager.j_lzl_l_p.lzl_li_pager_s p a")
    if len(lzl_next) != 0:
        for h in lzl_next:
            href = h.xpath("@href").extract_first().strip()
            text = h.xpath("./text()").extract_first().strip()

            if text == u'下一页':
                index = response.url.find("&pn=")
                next_url = response.url[:index + 4] + href[1:]
                yield scrapy.Request(next_url, callback=self.parse)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It's obvious that not using BS4 can parse response well! ( so it's not the response incorrect, but **the way of parse** is wrong ), I change your code to process emoji unicode( or it will occur error ), and the final version code works well! Thank you very much!